# Can anyone explain how we get output for numpy.poly function

Tags: python, numpy

I want to know what happens behind the scene when we call `numpy.poly` function. An example demonstration will be appreciated.

```
>>> numpy.poly((0, 0, 0)) # Multiple root example
array([1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Hi, on all the pages in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.poly.html), there is a link to [the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.4/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L32-L146) (see the upper right corner.)

Comment: I was not able to understand examples over there, as there are direct solutions posted, no explanation is given

Comment: On the documentation page (linked by @Dair's comment), make sure to read the 'Parameters' and 'Returns' descriptions for the function. It describes it very clearly if you have an understanding of how polynomials work.

Comment: can you explain how we get output for array (0,0,0) as 1,0,0,0  @Max Collier

Comment: @BhushanNavgire just posted an answer

Comment: Jump to the correct answer by @jasonharper - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54120391/984471

Answer (score 7):

A polynomial with roots at 'a', 'b', and 'c' can easily be created by writing `(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)`, which can be multiplied out to produce -abc + abx + acx + bcx - ax<sup>2</sup> - bx<sup>2</sup> - cx<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>3</sup>.  In your case, with a, b, c all zero, that simplifies to x<sup>3</sup>.  Your result of `[1, 0, 0, 0]` is a representation of that polynomial as an array of coefficients.

Comment: Thankx a lot dude. you solution is the perfect answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @jason's answer:

The `np.poly` code, for basic cases can be simplified to:

```
def foo(seq):
    a = np.array([1.])
    for s in seq:
        a = np.convolve(a, [1,-s])
    return a

In [39]: foo([0,0,0])
Out[39]: array([1., 0., 0., 0.])
In [40]: np.poly([0,0,0])
Out[40]: array([1., 0., 0., 0.])
In [41]: foo([2,0,-2])
Out[41]: array([ 1.,  0., -4.,  0.])
In [42]: np.poly([2,0,-2])
Out[42]: array([ 1.,  0., -4.,  0.])
In [43]: foo([.1,.2,.3])
Out[43]: array([ 1.   , -0.6  ,  0.11 , -0.006])
In [44]: np.poly([.1,.2,.3])
Out[44]: array([ 1.   , -0.6  ,  0.11 , -0.006])
```

What `np.convolve` does, and why it works for this task, is another question layer.

Printing `a` after each iteration:

```
In [46]: foo([.1,.2,.3])
[ 1.  -0.1]
[ 1.   -0.3   0.02]
[ 1.    -0.6    0.11  -0.006]
```

Grouping @jason's equation:

```
-abc + abx + acx + bcx - ax2 - bx2 - cx2 + x3
-abc + (ab + ac + bc)*x + (- a - b - c)*x2 + x3

-.1*.2*.3, (.1*.2 + .1*.3 + .2*.3), (-.1-.2-.3), 1
-.006, .02+.03+.06, -.6, 1
```

or building incrementally

```
-a + x
-ab + (-a-b)x + x2
-abc + ...
```

Comment: The answer could have started from @jasonharper's answer, then it would all make sense easily. Also a link to jasonharper's answer at the begin will help.